# Objective C error: "can't locate the database". How to solve?

Tags: sql, objective-c, database, xcode

I am attempting to create an application using objective C and a database. In one of my key controllers, I have the following code to locate the database:

```
self.myArrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString * path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase.rdb"];

BOOL success = [fm fileExistsAtPath:path];
if (!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't locate the database\n");
}
```

At runtime, I get the error message that the application can't locate the database. myDatabase.rdb has been added to the supporting files for my project. I do not understand how this error is happening - can someone please help explain how and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Explain: "myDatabase.rdb is saved in the exact same folder as myController above". How is it saved there? Is it a pre-loaded database added at compile time? If so it needs to be added to the project. If it is created at run-time the location the location is incorrect, the app's resource directory is read-only.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was misleading. The database is added to the project in the Supporting Files category.

Comment: Did you add it to the project, not just add it to the "Supporting Files" group? Is in the target "Build Settings" "Copy Files"? You do realize that files in the bible can not be written to?

Comment: In the prompt that appeared when I dropped it into "Supporting Files", I ticked the box "Copy items if needed". Is there something else I should be doing as well?

Comment: I tried it again. It works now: thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db file needs to be added to the target "Copy Files".

[image]

Note that the app bundle is read only.